# Mac Ports Mavericks Ghostscript Install Fails

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, ghostscript, macports

I have done the following:

1. Upgrade my mac to Maverick
2. Installed Mac Ports For Maverick

Recently, my MongoDB stopped working because there was an error with libboost. I tried to do an update but the update always fails when trying to install ghostscript:

```
Error: Failed to configure ghostscript, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/work/ghostscript-9.10/config.log
Error: org.macports.configure for port ghostscript returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port ghostscript for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/main.log
```

Now going into the config.log, I get this:

```
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
```

configure: exit 77

What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here (http://www.macports.org/install.php) and here (https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)?  In particular, did you run `xcode-select --install` and install Xcode (available for free from the Mac App Store)?

Comment: Yes, I did that all also. Sorry forgot that into step 3.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall and reinstall everything?

Comment: It's not clear to me from the log excerpt exactly what problem you are running into. The MacPorts project recommends that you reinstall all ports when you do a major OS X upgrade. The migration web page shows a couple of ways to do that semi-automatically and, if you are using the default binary install of the MacPorts base software with the default settings in `/opt/local/etc/macports`, there may be pre-built binaries for many of the ports you need. If you are upgrading from a near current version of MP's base, you *might* be able to get away with using `--enforce-variants` on `upgrade`.

Comment: If you are having trouble sorting out your Mac Ports environment in order to install MongoDB, an alternative would be to follow the steps for [Manual Installation on OS X](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#manual-installation) which uses prebuilt binaries. Installing binaries removes any headaches from library conflicts :).